# Why is the divergence of the velocity field for point charges zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

If I want to show that a point charge distribution (a sum of delta functions in space) respects the continuity equation, then I must use that the velocity field for each charge $q_k$, $\bf{v_k}$, is solenoidal: $\nabla \cdot \bf{v_k}$ $=0 $. This seems intuitive insofar as I expect that it relates to conservation of charge, but where does it come from precisely/is this an assumption we are making about the world which codifies conservation of charge? It is stated as a fact in a derivation given by Zangwill in Modern Electrodynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the velocity is that of a point charge, it's only a function of time, not of position, so all its position derivatives are zero. It's not a field, to put it in different terms. It's a constant as far as gradient/divergence/curl are concerned.

Comment: Ah I see now. It is definitely not a field, and instead is a vector function of the parameter $t$. Thank you!